How much slower is pointer arithmetic vs using a pointer?
I had a great idea to save memory by allocating a whole bunch, and then just doing pointer arithmetic on a lower type of number.
/* NORMAL VERSION */
int a = 5;
int b = 3;
int *ptr = &b;

int c = *ptr;

/* LOW MEM VERSION */
int *start = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
start[0] = 5;
start[1] = 3;

uint8_t ptr = 1 * sizeof(int);
int c = *(start + ptr);

The focus is on the first version of the pointer being a normal pointer, whereas the second version is an offset from a known starting pointer. The question is what the speed difference between accessing a pure pointer and accessing one using pointer arithmetic (or index) would be. And whether the memory saving of between 50 and 87.5% on pointers only would warrant the effort.

No way to tell, modern compilers and CPU have a lot of optimizations built it. The same C code may be slower/faster in different contexts. Unless you're working with an old compiler that always generates exactly the same predicable assembly, and your CPU has exact timings for all assembly, I wouldn't bother.
Optimize for readability and communicating the intention, do not nitpick optimizations.

How are you saving memory? a and b uses the same amount of memory as that referenced by start; it's just on the stack instead of on the heap.

Unless something like this makes a noticeable impact on the performance of your code, you really shouldn't micro-optimize like this.  Have you tested the difference in performance between the "normal version" and the "low mem version"? Also, using malloc() is unnecessary here. Even if you use malloc() like you did above, you still have to free the allocated memory once you're done with it.

"Normal version" uses memory for 3 ints and one pointer. "Low mem version" uses memory for 3 ints, one pointer, one uint8_t, and malloc's additional internal usage of memory for its bookkeeping. "Low mem version" uses more memory, though some of it is shifted to dynamic memory. This doesn't take into account whatever might be optimized to use registers or totally omitted. No memory saving here. And malloc adds execution time and the need to call free.

Also, *(start + ptr) is exactly the same as start[ptr] (and ptr[start]). [With arrays, why is it the case that a[5] == 5a]?


I had a great idea to save memory by allocating a whole bunch, and then just doing pointer arithmetic....

It is a good idea.  Such a good idea, in fact, that it's already being done by the heap manager (which is the implementation behind malloc and free).
When you call malloc to allocate a small-ish amount of memory, the heap manager gives you a chunk of a larger block of memory that it allocated from the OS.  Asking the heap manager for a large block and trying to manage it yourself as a bunch of chunks is actually duplicate work.
Yes, the heap manager incurs some overhead to keep track of how the big block of memory was carved into smaller chunks.  But you'd have to do that as well.  Maybe, you could do it with slightly less overhead by making it less general.

Pointer arithmetic isn't hard, but it is prone to mistakes.  Take a look at your "LOW MEM" snippet:
uint8_t ptr = 1 * sizeof(int);
int c = *(start + ptr);

ptr is the byte offset of the int you want to access, but your base pointer start is an int *, so when you try to assign the second int in the array to c, you actually are reading from the wrong part of the allocation, which—at best— is uninitialized memory, but it could even be a buffer overrun.
I'm not trying to criticize your skills.  I think this error should serve as a reminder that it's really easy to make mistakes with pointer arithmetic.  The heap manager is already battle-tested, optimized, and possibly even hardened against certain classes of exploits.
Rolling your own memory manager is worthwhile only if you know your program has certain access patterns that you can handle more optimally than a general purpose heap manager.  (Rolling your own can also be educational, so if you have the itch, go ahead and experiment.  But if you want to use it in production code, prepare for a major effort.)
There's currently a lot of talk about so-called memory-safe languages (like Rust) and finding ways to improve the safety of other languages (like C++).  Moving all of your variables into dynamic memory that you access exclusively with pointer arithmetic would be moving in the other direction.

Modern optimizing compilers are very good down at this level.  If you write one loop that uses indexes to step through an array for a calculation and another version that does the same calculation by incrementing a pointer through the array, it's likely the compiler is going to generate the same code.
When you try to force everything in your program into one model, you can actually hinder the optimizer.  If you have an automatic or static variable that the compiler determines is unnecessary, it can eliminate it.  But you have an unnecessary variable written to a dynamic memory allocation, it's probably impossible for the optimizer to get rid of it.

Read What and where are the stack and heap? to know more about stack and heap.


The question is what the speed difference between accessing a pure pointer and accessing one using pointer arithmetic (or index) would be.

It depends on the context. For example if we are to take your first example and put it in a program like this:
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 3;
    int *ptr = &b;
    int c = *ptr;    
    printf("%d\n", c);
}

Then all the pointer access and de-referencing is simply optimized out and on the assembler level (x86) we end up with something like mov esi, 3. That is, move the number 3 into a CPU register, call printf based on that register and forget all about these variables. Which is obviously very efficient code.
So we can't really discuss performance without a very specific scenario in mind, because obviously the above scenario will drastically outperform your second one (or will it?).

As for your second example uint8_t ptr = 1 * sizeof(int); is obviously a bug. This results in start + 4 on mainstream 32/64 bit computers, but start only has 2 items. This is a classic beginner bug when it comes to pointer arithmetic: the type of the pointer operand of the + is what determines how many bytes to increment with. Since start is int the start + 4 results in start + 4*4 bytes. You need to familiarize yourself with the beginner-level topic of pointer arithmetic way before even considering manual performance optimizations, which is an advanced topic. About as advanced as C programming gets, probably.
Another thing we can say about performance is that heap allocation in itself is very slow. So the bottleneck in the second program is the malloc call.
However... the compiler is allowed to optimize that part too. So if we once again write a minimal program but with the second version (bug fixed):
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int *start = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    start[0] = 5;
    start[1] = 3;
    int c = *(start + 1);
    printf("%d\n", c);
    free(start);
}

...then we find ourselves staring at mov esi, 3 once again. The compiler aggressively optimized away the whole malloc call and everything. As long as the behavior of the program isn't affected, the C start is quite lenient towards which optimizations that are allowed.
So both versions actually resulted in identical code, in this particular context. The compiler is simply very good at optimizing code whenever dealing with fixed numerical constants. In order to prevent it from doing such optimizations we'd have to write code where it can't predict the outcome at compile-time. Here's some code actually results in a malloc call and heap allocation:
void func(size_t n, int val)
{
    int *start = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    start[n-1] = val;
    int c = *(start + 1);
    printf("%d\n", c);
    free(start);
}


As for int c = *(start + i);, we may also note that this is poor style. That code is 100% equivalent to int c = start[i]; with no performance gain/loss whatsoever. *(start + i) is just much harder to read and understand than start[i], so we should always use the start[i] style. In fact the [] operator is always applied on a pointer and never on an array - see Do pointers support "array style indexing"?

Finally, to get to the essence of your question: what's the performance difference between int *ptr = &b; int c = *ptr; and int c = start[i]; in general terms, when neither are optimized out as seen above. The former is then faster or equivalent to the latter but never slower.
Because in the former case we are dealing with a fixed address known to the compiler at compile-time. Any sensible compiler will not allocate ptr at all but just grab the hard-coded address. But in the latter case, start was obtained from malloc, so not only is the address unknown to the compiler at compile-time, it has to perform the actual arithmetic of start + i too. That is still a very fast operation, to the point where manual optimization is senseless, but it can't be faster than the former example.
In general, accessing an array through an index is a good way to increase performance though. Quite often the fastest possible code no matter target system comes from forming a look-up table and then access it through an index. That's an execution speed over memory optimization which is viable on pretty much any system. But on high-end systems with data cache memory, it is particularly viable since the array can then be loaded into cache in advance. And the program accessing it might also be pre-fetched into instruction cache.
